# Seeing close-vote details if I've already voted

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

If I've already voted to close a question, it would still be nice to see the details of others' votes — the suggested migration if it's being marked as off topic, or the suggested duplicate if it's being marked as an exact duplicate, for instance. Instead, I only see "You have already voted to close this question" and the overall category.

[image]

Comment: Please use SE's normal image upload feature, not a triply-redirected, mystery-meat src.

Comment: I just asked [a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204611/225437) that got closed as a duplicate of this one.  They're similar, and I think one answer/feature implementation could answer them both.  I was asking because I wanted access to the off-topic sub-dialog though, not the duplicate subdialog.

Comment: The duplicate subdialog is important, too, though, since not everyone that votes to close as a duplicate votes for the _same_ duplicate, and people can remove their "possible duplicate of …" comments.

Answer (score 3):

It's great that they show the same close dialog, just with the button dimmed to show that you couldn't vote again.  The counts show when you open that dialog, but it could be modified to show the breakdown of duplicate and off-topic votes.

Answer (score 1):

The exact duplicate gets posted as a comment when that vote is made.

The vote counts are shown.

Why wouldn't you read the suggested migration when suggesting to migrate?

Comment: If I made the first close vote, it would be nice to see if other people are agreeing with me.

Comment: @jtbandes It would be nice if they mailed you a cheque, too, but what purpose would it serve? :P

Comment: This. They *are* already shown. This information is all already available. The feature request is redundant.

Comment: @Cody: How are details for migration votes shown?

Comment: @CodyGray Not everyone that votes to close as a duplicate votes for the _same_ duplicate, and users that vote to close as a duplicate can delete the comment that says "possible duplicate of …".