# Close button disabled on mobile if already voted

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, mobile-web

> Related: [Seeing close-vote details if I've already voted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101571/seeing-close-vote-details-if-ive-already-voted)

On the full site, you can still click a close link and check out the current vote counts, even if you've already vote to close yourself. This becomes useful at times.

However, on the mobile site, the close button is dimmed and cannot be tapped—no matter what you try.

[image]

Looking at the source, it may be [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). :/ Why so?

[image]

Comment: The mobile site has limited functionality compared to the main site. This is completely by design. I'm just glad they added in "vote to close". I can't browse SO without it.

Comment: @TheEstablishment: I know that, but what's the point of disabling the "close" button _on purpose_? If you have a close button, make it useful, right? The normal vote-to-close works properly, so the same js is being loaded anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be deployed in the next builds (`rev 2234` on meta and `rev 1600` on main)