# Access to the off-topic sub-dialog again after voting to close

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, user-interface

When I vote to close a question as off-topic vote, I often copy the text of the close reason from the close vote dialog to post as a comment to explain to the asker *why* the question is off-topic.    Unfortunately, unless I want to visit another question page, I have to do this *before* I actually cast the close vote, because once the vote has been cast, the dialog for the “close (n)” link doesn't allow me to get back into the off-topic subreasons.  To get the text for a comment, I have to open another question that I haven't voted on, open the close dialog, and copy from there.  This also means that I can't (if I wanted to), check on the *specific* off-topic reason that I voted for.  I'd like to be able to get back into the off-topic submenu after I've voted to close.

This obviously isn't a huge priority, but it would make my “workflow” a little bit easier for those times that I forget to copy the text first.

[image: close vote dialog after casting vote]

Comment: I really don't see such comments as beneficial.  If you're going to take the time to comment it should be because you have something to add beyond just the message the system is inevitably going to display to the user.

Comment: I don't usually post _just_ that text.  Usually more along the lines of "Reasons for closing questions on StackOverflow include: ‘Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include **valid code to reproduce it** — in the question itself.’ and ‘Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include **attempted solutions**, why they didn't work, and the **expected results**.’  What code have you written so far, and what didn't work about it?  What were the expected results?"  That is, I usually…

Comment: …use it as a starting point, emphasize the bits that are lacking in a particular question, and elaborate.  E.g., [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19810572/is-it-possible-to-extract-rdfa-from-html-page-using-easyrdf#comment29457239_19810572).

Comment: @Servy, I thought that it was beneficial in the sense that they warn the user *beforehand* on what's going to happen with their Q.  And the user can amend on time. Ideally, this kind of comment has to be cleaned up after closure.

Comment: @brasofilo I often do this _before_ I actually cast a close vote, so I don't pften run into this problem.  Some of the tags I'm active in, though, get so low views that I'm not really worried about voting early.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, I don't use this technique regularly. Many times we can condense all the closing reason in a single sentence that points to what the OP can improve especifically on their Question.

Comment: @brasofilo But we're programmers!  Summaries and intuitive explanations lead to bugs and unfounded assumptions.  Askers should provide actual source and verbatim error messages;  shouldn't we do the same with close reasons? (That's mostly tongue-in-cheek. :))